# Ethereum API "Out of Gas"

Tags: go-ethereum

when I look at the ethereum explorer for this transaction I see error "out of gas":
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf6dba06461464d2d0aa351e1e236e5021a0c4bf5309f30a5ab7c0ce7e82ba965

When looking at the pure JSON-Date from the API, how can I determine this "out of gas" error?
https://api.infura.io/v1/jsonrpc/mainnet/eth_getTransactionByHash?params=[%220xf6dba06461464d2d0aa351e1e236e5021a0c4bf5309f30a5ab7c0ce7e82ba965%22]

Thanks